# How come you say "best part" if meaning "most of something"?

Tags: etymology, adjectives

When I read the first time that someone *spend the best/better part of the day doing something*, I took *best* literally.

Although I now know its meaning, it's confusing me over and over again whenever I read such a sentence.

What's the reason for saying *best part* and not, for instance, *most part*?

Comment: I suspect the answer will be "idiom," "pure idiom" or "damn idiom."  In general the 'best part' of the day indicates the day's highlight, while 'better part' is quantitative, denoting most of the day.  I don't have access to a good etymology; some research on the historical uses of 'good, better, best' might add some light to the issue.

Comment: There's an obvious etymology: if you split a cake (for example) in half, the "best part" is usually the biggest.

Answer (score 5):

The third definition of *best* in the ‘Oxford English Dictionary’ is ‘largest, most’. It is first attested in collocation with ‘part’ in 1538: ‘Twenty nobles, of which I think he doth owe the best part for his rent.’

*Best*, like *good*, has many meanings. It isn’t hard to see how the largest part of something came to  be regarded as the best.